# Starting an activity and a fragment from a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

TL,DR: How to start from "Activity A" both the "Activity B" and the fragments that will be shown in it.

I'm new to Android Studio so I'm clueless about most things concerning fragments. I'm working on an app that calculates information about different shapes. At first the user can pick a shape, then they are taken to an activity where they input the dimensions. What I'm trying to do is, instead of creating an activity for every shape, I created a single activity in which I'd like to start different fragments. I created a single fragment for every dimension (say side a, side b and so on...).
It's a bit hard to explain for me but what I'm trying to do is, from the first activity - "Menu.java" through a button open up a second activity- "Input.java" activity (containing just a confirm button) along with some fragments as soon as the "Input" activity starts (depending on the shape the fragments may vary, whether just in position or over all in which are loaded and which not - the reason i think i need to do it like this).
To simplify (and hopefully make it a bit more understandable) - from "Activity A" start both the "Activity B" and the fragments that will be shown in it.

I don't have any code besides the fragments themselves and the buttons set up because like I said I'm mostly clueless and I'm thankful for every advice or at least clarification that it isn't possible. Hovewer if there is any other information that can help or you want me to try to explain it a bit better just make a comment and I'll and what you need.

Thanks a lot

--EDIT--
here is all the code I have ready:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
}

public void inputSquare(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Input.class);
```

//Here is where I'd like to start let's say fragment "Input_A_Fragment" in the Input class (or even if this isn't the way/place to do it please le me know)

```
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: include code of what you are doing to help reviewers to provide an answer

Comment: I am slightly confused with how you want to display fragments on your second activity.
Tell me how many fragments u have and how do you want to display it? Or tell me what u want to provide the user with when they go on the second activity

Comment: @Nero For example when they choose a square in the Menu the second activity opens and the only fragment there would be "Input_A_Fragment". But if they chose let's say a cylinder, two fragments would be shown: "Input_R_Fragment" and a "Input_V_Fragment". All the fragments consist only of a simple text view with an edit text component below it.

Comment: So I understand this correctly, sometimes the second activity will have one fragment and sometimes it will have two?

Comment: @Nero Yes, depending on how many dimensions do I need to calculate circumference, surface, volume etc. of the chosen object

Comment: Ok as for final question, what's the max number fragment will be on the second activity?

Comment: @Nero The maximal number of fragments should be 5. And thank you for your patience :D